# How to create a specialized and default versions of a function that take base and derived classes?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have the following class architecture:

```
class Animal 
{
 // ...
}

class Cat : public Animal
{
 // ...
}

class Dog : public Animal
{
 // ...
}

// + Several other derived classes
```

In another section of my code, I have a function that goes through a list of Animals and needs to perform specialized actions in the case of several of the derived classes and a default action otherwise. How can I handle this situation elegantly, given the following constraints:

1. I'd like to keep the new code outside of Animal and its derived
   classes because of separation of concerns.
2. I'd like to avoid using a switch statement on types or enums as it feels very smelly.

Comment: You can read about [double dispatch in C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch#Double_dispatch_in_C.2B.2B) to get some ideas.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "a list of Animals"? Do you mean a `list<Animal*>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way - use the concept-model idiom (my name):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct AnimalConcept {
    virtual ~AnimalConcept() = default;

    virtual void make_noise() const = 0;
};

// default case
void make_noise_for(const AnimalConcept&)
{
    std::cout << "no noise" << std::endl;
}

template<class Model>
struct AnimalModel : AnimalConcept
{

    void make_noise() const override {
        make_noise_for(static_cast<const Model&>(*this));
    }
};

// some models

struct Cat : AnimalModel<Cat>
{

};

struct Dog : AnimalModel<Dog>
{

};

struct Giraffe : AnimalModel<Giraffe>
{

};

// separation of concerns - specific overrides

void make_noise_for(const Cat&) {
    std::cout << "meow\n";
}

void make_noise_for(const Dog&) {
    std::cout << "woof\n";
}

// test

using namespace std;

int main(){
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<const AnimalConcept>> animals;
    animals.emplace_back(new Cat);
    animals.emplace_back(new Dog);
    animals.emplace_back(new Giraffe);

    for (const auto& p : animals) {
        p->make_noise();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

expected output:

```
meow
woof
no noise
```

And here's another way to implement it (this one is nicer since it allows all animals to have unrelated interfaces):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct AnimalConcept {
    virtual ~AnimalConcept() = default;

    virtual void make_noise() const = 0;
};

// default case
template<class T>
void make_noise_for(const T&)
{
    std::cout << "this animal makes no noise" << std::endl;
}

template<class Model>
struct AnimalModel : AnimalConcept
{
    template<class...Args>
    AnimalModel(Args&&...args)
    : _model { std::forward<Args>(args)... }
    {}

private:
    void make_noise() const override {
        make_noise_for(_model);
    }

    Model _model;
};

// some models

struct Cat
{
    Cat(std::string name)
    : _name { std::move(name) }
    {}

    const std::string& name() const {
        return _name;
    }

private:
    std::string _name;
};

struct Dog
{
    Dog(std::string name, int age)
    : _name { std::move(name) }
    , _age { age }
    {}

    const std::string& name() const {
        return _name;
    }

    int age() const {
        return _age;
    }

private:
    std::string _name;
    int _age;
};

struct Giraffe
{

};

// separation of concerns - specific overrides

void make_noise_for(const Cat& c) {
    std::cout << c.name() << " says meow\n";
}

void make_noise_for(const Dog& d) {
    std::cout << "the dog called " << d.name() << " who is " << d.age() << " years old says woof\n";
}

// test

using namespace std;

int main(){
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<const AnimalConcept>> animals;
    animals.emplace_back(new AnimalModel<Cat> { "felix" });
    animals.emplace_back(new AnimalModel<Dog> { "fido", 2 });
    animals.emplace_back(new AnimalModel<Giraffe>);

    for (const auto& p : animals) {
        p->make_noise();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

expected output:

```
felix says meow
the dog called fido who is 2 years old says woof
this animal makes no noise
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of the following to get type based dispatch.

1. Provide for every class to return a type ID associated with it.
2. Provide a virtual function in the base class to get the type ID associated with an object.
3. Provide a way for registration of functions based on type ID.
4. When the time comes for execution of the top level function, search for a registered function given an animal's type ID. If a function is registered, call it. Otherwise, use the default function.

```
// Implement this function in a .cpp file.
int getNextTypeID()
{
   static int typeID = 0;
   return ++typeID;
}

class Animal 
{
   virtual int getTypeID();
};

class Cat : public Animal
{
   static int getID()
   {
      static int typeID = getNextTypeID();
   }

   virtual int getTypeID()
   {
      return getID();
   }
};

class Dog : public Animal
{
   static int getID()
   {
      static int typeID = getNextTypeID();
   }

   virtual int getTypeID()
   {
      return getID();
   }
};
```

foo.h:

```
typedef void (*AnimalFunction)(Animal& a);

int registerAnimalFunctor(int typeID, AnimalFunction f);

void foo(Animal& a);
```

foo.cpp:

```
typedef std::map<int, AnimalFunction> AnimalFunctionMap;

AnimalFunctionMap& getAnimalFunctionMap()
{
   static AnimalFunctionMap theMap;
   return theMap;
}

int registerAnimalFunctor(int typeID, AnimalFunction f)
{
   getAnimalFunctionMap()[typeID] = f;
   return 0;
}

void defaultAnimalFunction(a)
{
   // Default action
}

void foo(Animal& a)
{
   AnimalFunctionMap& theMap = getAnimalFunctionMap();
   AnimalFunctionMap::iterator iter = theMap.find(a.getTypeID());
   if ( iter != theMap.end() )
   {
      iter->second(a);
   }
   else
   {
      defaultAnimalFunction(a);
   }
}
```

cat_foo.cpp:

```
void CatFunction(Animal& a)
{
   // Cat action.
}

int dummy = registerAnimalFunctor(Cat::getID(), CatFunction);
```

dog_foo.cpp:

```
void DogFunction(Animal& a)
{
   // Dog action.
}

int dummy = registerAnimalFunctor(Dog::getID(), DogFunction);
```